# Who are the characters on the two secret rubber straps for season one?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

One of the pieces of merchandise for Symphogear season one is a "trading rubber strap", about half way down [the second page of goods on the official site](http://www.symphogear.com/prod06_2.html). There are ten varieties - Hibiki, Miku, Ryouko, and Chris in regular clothing; Hibiki, Chris, Tsubasa, and Kanade clad in Symphogear; and then two more secret ones that are shown only in silhouette.

[image: goods16.jpg]

Who are the characters depicted on the two secret straps? I can't tell from the silhouettes, though the shape of the one on the left looks suspiciously like Tsubasa's hair.

Comment: Haha! I finally got a tumbleweed badge!

Comment: Is it possible that they're sneak peaks into season 2's Shirabe and Kirika?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still looking for an answer, it's a second Kanade and Tsubasa.
Here is what they look like. ([Source](http://plamoya.com/en/senki-zessho-symphogear-petanko-trading-rubber-strap-10pcs-p-49457.html).)

[image: Rubber stamp samples]